# How to debug JavaScript code used by Selenium in a Java project?

Tags: javascript, selenium, debugging

The following code is throwing a `TimeoutException`:

```
 WebElement checkbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("displayedCheckbox")));
```

I found out that the `isElementDisplayed` JS function is returning `false` when the checkbox  is clearly displayed in the viewport.

While debugging I realized that the method `isDisplayed()` in `RemoteWebElement` class contains the following line:

```
Object value = execute(DriverCommand.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED(id)).getValue();
```

which seems to be super close to the boundary between Java and JavaScript.

Looking for its relationship with JS I found a definition in the file [selenium/javascript/chrome-driver/atoms.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/eda884abbaa36795082738563a5ffa50682fa153/javascript/chrome-driver/atoms.js) :

```
/**
 * Determines whether an element is what a user would call "shown". Mainly based
 * on bot.dom.isShown, but with extra intelligence regarding shadow DOM.
 *
 * @param {!Element} elem The element to consider.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_inComposedDom Whether to check if the element is shown
 *     within the composed DOM; defaults to false.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_ignoreOpacity Whether to ignore the element's opacity
 *     when determining whether it is shown; defaults to false.
 * @return {boolean} Whether or not the element is visible.
 */
webdriver.chrome.isElementDisplayed = function(elem,
                                               opt_inComposedDom,
                                               opt_ignoreOpacity) {
  if (!bot.dom.isShown(elem, opt_ignoreOpacity)) {
    return false;
  }
  // if it's not invisible then check if the element is within the shadow DOM
  // of an invisible element, using recursive calls to this function
  if (SHADOW_DOM_ENABLED) {
    var topLevelNode = elem;
    while (topLevelNode.parentNode) {
      topLevelNode = topLevelNode.parentNode;
    }
    if (topLevelNode instanceof ShadowRoot) {
      return webdriver.chrome.isElementDisplayed(topLevelNode.host,
                                                 opt_inComposedDom);
    }
  }
  // if it's not invisible, or in a shadow DOM, then it's definitely visible
  return true;
};
```

My debugging journey has ended there because I don't know how to keep debugging and I cannot log a bug for Selenium because I cannot give access nor provide a sample project with the code and I don't know what is going wrong on the JS side...

Can you please tell me if there is something else that can be done to figure out what's the issue? Maybe setting a switch for debugging when running my Java code, or running some JS code on browser's console?

**Note:** Locating the element works fine. I can even send a `click()` to the element; however, the `wait.until()` times out because the `elementToBeClickable()` method never returns `true`; and to be precise, the `execute(DriverCommand.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED(id)).getValue()` which is called by the `elementToBeClickable()` is the one that never returns `true`; therefore, as the call goes up on the call stack, the `false` propagates back to the `wait.until()` and after continously polling and waiting for X seconds, it eventually times out.

### Edit (requested code):

HTML:

```
<div class="card" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" data-xyz="">
  <img class="image_in_card" src="img.png" alt="Image" data-xyz="">
  <div class="card_content" data-xyz="">
    <div data-xyz="" class="checkbox_wrapper" id="id_checkbox_wrapper">
      <input class="card_input" type="checkbox" id="displayedCheckbox" name="name_checkbox">
      <label class="card_label" for="id_checkbox">Checkbox
        <span data-xyz="" class="stylish_span">
          <svg id="id_svg" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20" class="svg_class" focusable="false">
            <title id="id_svg_title">SVG Title</title>
            <path id="id_path" d="M10 10">
            </path>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="card_text" data-xyz="">Some text.
  </p>
</div>
```

JAVA:

```
protected final Wait<WebDriver> wait;
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

Comment: Include the HTML of the checkbox.  (or the whole page)  That'll give us some clue as to what might be happening.  Also include your initialization/creation of the  "wait" object.

Comment: @pcalkins done. Any idea on how to debug JS code there?

Comment: Right now it looks like the id is wrong, and "wait" is not defined.  (Just "stdWait") You're looking for By.id("displayedCheckbox") when the checkbox's id is "id_checkbox".  You sure what's throwing the timeout is not element does not exist?  (maybe include the full timeout exception in your post)  You really shouldn't need to debug chromedriver... but I believe the source code is available.  You'd need to get the driver running in your IDE...  if you need dev protocol stuff, you'd likewise need to use source for Chromium and get that running in the IDE.

Comment: @pcalkins I corrected the bad id I introduced because I redacted the HTML. I actually use a location strategy other than the ID but I used that to exemplify. The code up there is very similar to the actual code I have, just omitted the specifics because for security reasons I cannot publish whatever I want. Whenever I use `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator)` I don't have any issues but my code times out with `elementTOBeClickable(locator)`. Whenever I send a `click()` to the element, it actually receives the click. The issue is that method `displayedCheckbox` returns false

Comment: It could be the label... when you use label-for attribute it extends the click area to the label element/text.   Selenium may be incorrectly checking that...(because it will try to click on the center of the element... which may now be different?) you could try clicking the label element instead to see if that helps or if the exception changes.  If it is clicking though, you might just try/catch the call, and ignore the exception.